# Как заставить coverage.py считать покрытие тестов методом черного ящика?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

При работе с coverage.py формируется отчет, например как на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меня не волнует реализация методов и функции, я хочу запустить coverage.py и получить отчет о покрытии тестов на основании только самих результатов работы функций(методов), а не их реализации(тела). Возможно ли такое?

Comment: Но в чём практический смысл такого неполноценного анализа покрытия?

Comment: в том, чтобы увидеть что покрыл все тестами вплоть до реализации или, что о забыл что-то протестировать